# Is Should + have + had correct?

Tags: grammar

Is should + have + had correct? 
As in example -- "I should have had more cakes"

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is correct.

From Practical English Usage:

> But should/ought to have + past participle can be used to talk about
>   unfulfilled past obligations: things which weren’t done, or which may
>   or may not have been done.
>   *I should have phoned Ed this morning, but I forgot.*